# Scala nested match pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm writing a sort of rules engine that traverses a tree and establishes a context for each sub-tree and then uses match conditions to validate the tree and infer information about the nodes.

I had hoped that I could use nested match conditions (on case class constructors) and match on outer and inner properties by using the same constructor property name like this:

```
val context = Foo(42, "Hello, World")
val items = List(
  Foo(42, "Hello, World"),
  Foo(42, "Bar"),
  Foo(24, "Hello, World"),
  Foo(2, "Goodbye")
)

def matchFoo(context: Foo, item: Foo): String = {
  context match {
    case Foo(num, text) =>
      item match {
        case Foo(num, text)           => "Exact match"
        case Foo(otherNum, text)      => "Text match"
        case Foo(num, otherText)      => "Number match"
        case Foo(otherNum, otherText) => "No match"
      }
  }

}

items.map(i => matchFoo(context, i))
```

But I just get 4 "Exact match" results. I'm guessing that the inner match of case Foo(num, text) hides the outer num, text variables and so matches any Foo item.

I can get around the issue by using explicit guard conditions but this is what I was trying to avoid:

```
val context = Foo(42, "Hello, World")
val items = List(
  Foo(42, "Hello, World"),
  Foo(42, "Bar"),
  Foo(24, "Hello, World"),
  Foo(2, "Goodbye")
)

def matchFoo(context: Foo, item: Foo): String = {
  context match {
    case Foo(num, text) =>
      item match {
        case Foo(otherNum, otherText) if otherNum == num && otherText == text => "Exact match"
        case Foo(otherNum, _) if otherNum == num => "Number match"
        case Foo(_, otherText) if otherText == text => "Text match"
        case _ => "No match"
      }
  }

}

items.map(i => matchFoo(context, i))
```

Is there anyway to achieve this or is guard conditions the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `num` and `text` in the inner pattern create new variable bindings that hide the outer ones, instead of using the values of the outer variables as values to match. You can quote the names with backticks (`) to get the behaviour you want:

```scala
case class Foo(num: Int, text: String)
val context = Foo(42, "Hello, World")
val items = List(
  Foo(42, "Hello, World"),
  Foo(42, "Bar"),
  Foo(24, "Hello, World"),
  Foo(2, "Goodbye")
)

def matchFoo(context: Foo, item: Foo): String = {
  context match {
    case Foo(num, text) =>
      item match {
        case Foo(`num`, `text`)       => "Exact match"
        case Foo(otherNum, `text`)    => "Text match"
        case Foo(`num`, otherText)    => "Number match"
        case Foo(otherNum, otherText) => "No match"
      }
  }

}

items.map(i => matchFoo(context, i))
```

Output:

```
val res0: List[String] = List(Exact match, Number match, Text match, No match)
```

This syntax is described in the [Scala Language Specification chapter on Pattern Matching, in the section titled "Stable Identifier Patterns"](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#stable-identifier-patterns):

> A *stable identifier pattern* is a [stable identifier](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#paths) *r*. The type of *r* must conform to the expected type of the pattern. The pattern matches any value *v* such that *r == v* (see [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#root-classes)).
>
> To resolve the syntactic overlap with a variable pattern, a stable identifier pattern may not be a simple name starting with a lower-case letter. However, it is possible to enclose such a variable name in backquotes; then it is treated as a stable identifier pattern.
>
> Example
> Consider the following class definition:
>
> ```scala
> class C { c =>
>   val x = 42
>   val y = 27
>   val Z = 8
>   def f(x: Int) = x match {
>     case c.x => 1  // matches 42
>     case `y` => 2  // matches 27
>     case Z   => 3  // matches 8
>     case x   => 4  // matches any value
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Here, the first three patterns are stable identifier patterns, while the last one is a variable pattern.

Comment: Tim, thank you very much for the solution... I've tested it and it works. If you have time could you explain how it works? I've tried to look up what the backtick quoting means in scala but so far I've drawn a blank. If it meant use the variable defined in the previous scope, then I could understand the answer.

Comment: @DavidRegan sorry for the delay. I've updated the answer with a link to and quote from the relevant part of the Scala Language Spec.